# URL problem : I am getting https://www.example.com/#/login. I want it to be https://www.example.com/login

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, url-routing

```
https://www.example.com/#/login
https://www.example.com/#/contact
https://www.example.com/#/home
```

I am using react router to create URL and everything like login , contact , home all are components.

Kindly suggest what can be done to make these URLs:

```
https://www.example.com/login
https://www.example.com/contact
https://www.example.com/home
```

Comment: Without further information on what your routing looks like, I would assume you are using a `<HashRouter/>` https://reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Comment: <HashRouter/> yes its being used.

Comment: Hi thankyou Miroslav . I replaced <HashRouter/> with browser router and now my application is working fine with URLs I need.